# Pointers for understanding the derivation of inference in linear dynamic systems

Tags: machine-learning, kalman-filter, graphical-model

I am trying to learn about the inference and maximization basically EM of the linear dynamic systems(Kalman filters for example) from Bishop's book of Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning. However, I am not being able to follow the derivations given in there.

I have got the basic idea of what Kalman filters are and what they are used for. However, I am a bit confused with the learning steps(basically the derivation of the equations and all). They seem a bit complicated. I have spent lot of time trying to figure them out. But I still have some issues. Can anyone suggest me where I can get the idea. Because in the book, they haven't given the details of how it is derived(the equations.

My question is how this is derived. It is a piece from the 2nd last image. I might be asking too much but I am really finding it difficult to get how this is derived. I would really appreciate if someone could give me some pointers

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On the derivation of the kalman filter in general, many good references exist. Among them,

[Simon, D. Optimal State Estimation: Kalman, H Infinity, and Nonlinear Approaches](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471708585)

[Durbin, J. and Koopman, S.J. Time Series Analysis by State Space Methods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/019964117X)

[Gibbs, B.P. Advanced Kalman Filtering, Least-Squares and Modeling: A Practical Handbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470529709)

For your precise question about the EM estimation with state-space models, perhaps you can turn to section 6.3 of

[Shumway, R.H. and Stoffer, D.S. Time Series Analysis and Its Applications: With R Examples](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008549LTO)

where it is nicely explained.

Comment: @Tusell. Thanks for the info. But I didn't understand the part related to the Bishop's book. I took a screenshot and added the part to this question. I could get a rough idea of the derivation of the kalman filter equations from this link http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aticourses.com%2Fkalman_filter.pdf&ei=0tvlUKuqBKaV0QGToIH4Bw&usg=AFQjCNHGdmas0f-cyisSuL-a3guD8hCbSA&sig2=cKBmAGxRt1GuvMrDHieVSQ&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.dmQ. But I didn't understand this part from the Bishop's book

Comment: @F.Tussel http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46944/confusion-related-to-kalman-filters-density-view

Comment: I need to get to grips with Kalman filters too. Any recommendations for a concise overview of the concept?

Comment: I think the first three references listed above are fine; the second will appeal to a wider audience, the first and third will probably be your choice if you have an engineering rather than an statistics background.

Comment: A great reference for Kalman filter is the Harvey text (http://www.amazon.com/Forecasting-Structural-Models-Kalman-Filter/dp/0521321964)

Comment: +1 for @rbatt recommendation. In fact, there are many fine books. Just to add a few more which, although old, are very good reads, you have the books by Gelb ("Applied Optimal Estimation") and Anderson & Moore ("Optimal Filtering"). Both again with an enginnering slant.